# Emacs terminal - the location before the command prompt

Tags: terminal-emacs, linux, ubuntu

My emacs terminal is currently displaying ;0user@Ubuntu: ~user@Ubuntu:~$".
This happened after my friend was using my laptop, and is persisting after uninstalling and reinstalling emacs, as well as deleting .emacs related files. I have tested the terminal on emacs on different accounts on my laptop, and it is not suffering from this, so migrating my files is an option, but annoying. Does anyone have a way of fixing the terminal on emacs? I'm running Ubuntu as well.

Comment: Some kind of issue with your `PS1` shell prompt, by the looks of it.  What does `echo $PS1` tell you (from a shell in that terminal) ?

Comment: Thank you, it was the PS1 value, I'm not sure how the value was differing between bash on Emacs and bash on a normal shell prompt, they were both pointing to the same location for the shell

Comment: You'd have to check your shell init file(s) to see what was setting it, and whether it was conditional on anything.  If you can't figure it out, update the question with the relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

The problem ended up being in my .bashrc file in my home directory. The issue was the PS1 value under the `case "$TERM" in` clause had somehow been modified. I changed this value to `PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '` to reset it back to the default.